# Scrolling Optimization for Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, optimization

We have a setup process that does some parallax scrolling effects at https://activegrade.appspot.com/?anonymous=true#firstsetup.  It runs WAY BETTER in Firefox than in Chrome - I think because of optimizations Chrome is trying to do:

1: It seems like scroll events aren't fired very often in chrome.  Notice how the floating images don't update with the page position in Chrome like they do in Firefox

2: It seems like Chrome is choking when a new div (the big colored sections) get on to the screen.  Maybe it was saving time elsewhere by not really loading these sections until the last possible moment?

I'm looking for suggestions for making this as smooth in Chrome as it is in firefox.  Working around these optimizations would be fine (I suspect #2 is more workaroundable than #1).

Answer (score 1):

Performance should be better, when you will utilize CSS3 transforms, instead of basic CSS positioning..

```
-webkit-transform: translate(x,y)
```

You can also read [this](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/blog/code-tutorials/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/) article, there are some advices how to make parallax effect smoother by changing only visible parts of the site.